# Why does jaxb log "No XmlSchema annotation found for <my package name>" when getting an instance of JAXBContext?

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, xsd

I have an xsd file that, when compiled using the jaxb-2 maven plugin, generates java source. 
The header for my xsd is:

```
<schema targetNamespace="example.company.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:prefix="example.company.com">
```

Whenever I attempt to get the JAXBContext for use in marshaling/unmarshaling using this code:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.company.example", com.company.example.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
```

I get hundreds of error messages in my console that look like this:

No XmlSchema annotation found for com.company.example

After all of those error messages, the marshaling works. I would like to get rid of the errors though.

The jaxb2 maven plugin is defined in my pom like so:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sourceforge.ccxjc</groupId>
                <artifactId>cc-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>xjc</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>

            <arguments>-enableIntrospection -verbose</arguments>
            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <packageName>com.company.example</packageName>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <failOnNoSchemas>true</failOnNoSchemas>
            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
            <arguments>-copy-constructor</arguments>
            <extension>true</extension>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though the package-info.java (that contains the `@XmlSchema` annotation) file that was generated along with the other model files from the XML Schema is not being compiled.

### Update

> I am running OSGi and using Java SE

You should make sure you import the `javax.xml.bind` package in your manifest.  Their can be `ClassLoader` issues with `javax` classes in OSGi environments.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. A class file for package-info.java is generated in my target directory.

Comment: @JustinWiseman - Are you running in a Java SE environment, in an application server, or an OSGi environment?

Comment: I am running OSGi and using Java SE

Comment: I have added javax.xml.bind to the imports listed in my maven-bundle-plugin plugin in the bundle containing the xsd and jaxb context loading code. This has not made a noticeable difference.

Comment: @JustinWiseman - You would need to add it to the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14402575/383861

Comment: It is in the manifest. This is the import section of my manifest:
Import-Package: org.slf4j;version="1.5.6",com.sun.activation.registries;
 version="[4.0,5)",javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.pars
 ers,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.
 xml.transform.sax,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xml.validation,myjav
 a.awt.datatransfer;version="[4.0,5)",org.w3c.dom,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sa
 x.ext,org.xml.sax.helpers,javax.xml.bind

Comment: I don't see `javax.xml.bind.annotation` which is the package for `@XmlSchema`.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. We are using a portable version of JAXB. This link http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/ indicates that android doesn't allow package level annotations. The author says he found a programmatic way to indicate those annotations. I'll look into that. Thank you for your help. I'm sure that had we been using normal JAXB your advice would have solved the problem.

Comment: @JustinWiseman - I appreciate the accept, but it would be better if you added what you found out as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't map your package to the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema". To do this, make your header like this:

```
<schema
  xmlns=...
  xmlns:po=....
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

Also, add this annotation to your class:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema (namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
```

For more information about XmlSchema, see these docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html

Comment: I don't understand. This link http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_04.aspx seems to indicate that the targetNamespace is not used as you think. "In principle the namespace has no meaning, but some companies have used the url where the schema is stored, as the targetNamespace and so some XML parsers will use this as a hint path for the schema e.g.: targetNamespace="http://www.microsoft.com/CommonTypes.xsd", but the following would be just as valid targetNamespace="my-common-types"."