# Hibernate, JAXB, Eclipse Plugin

Tags: hibernate, eclipse-plugin, jaxb, eclipse-rcp

i am trying to combine JAXB (as provided in the dom4j by Hibernate), Hibernate (4.1.3) and Eclipse (4.2) plug ins.

My "core" plugin contains a XMLUserType that takes a given pojo (annotated with @XmlRootElement and the rest; from another plug in) and converts it into an XML and vice versa. Unmarshalling works fine with this code (the cls is the class as given per string by a parameter:

```
public Object fromXMLString(final String xml) {
    if (null != xml) {
        final ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cls.getClassLoader());

            final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);
            final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

            final StreamSource sr = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));
            final JAXBElement<?> element = unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr, cls);
            return cls.cast(element.getValue());
        } catch (final JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void setParameterValues(final Properties parameters) {
    final String clsName = (String) parameters.get("ClassType");
    try {
        this.cls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(clsName);
    } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

unfortunatly marshalling just failes and i have no clue why.

```
public static Document convertToXML(final Object pojo, final Class<?> type) throws SystemException {
    Document ret = null;
    final ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(type.getClassLoader());
        final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
        final Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        final DocumentResult dr = new DocumentResult();

        marshaller.marshal(pojo, dr);

        final Document document = dr.getDocument();
        ret = document;
    } catch (final JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It dosnt matter whether or not the ClassLoader is set. It always fails with this exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type 
"packagingdetails.PackagingDetails" as an element because it is missing an 
@XmlRootElement annotation
```

I belive that the reason is either one of this reasons:
1. The annotations are represented by proxies and can therefore not be resolved
2. The ClassLoader makes trouble...

Regarding 1.: I noticed that (i tried to use that to get the name of the XmlRootElement to create a JAXBElement, but this seems not to be feasible...; my JAXBType should remain generic)

```
final Annotation[] annotations = type.getAnnotations();
XmlRootElement xmlRootElement = null;
for (final Annotation a : annotations) {
    if (XmlRootElement.class.isAssignableFrom(a.annotationType())) {
        xmlRootElement = (XmlRootElement) a;
        break;
    }
}
```

always fails...

Has anyone any Ideas???

Thanks
Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be sure that you import the `javax.xml.bind` package or the JAXB public API bundle in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

**OSGi Example (MOXy used as JAXB (JSR-222) provider)**

- [Moxy error with Karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942750/moxy-error-with-karaf/12943115#12943115)